# JPA Unidrectional OneToMany via JoinColumn Returning Same Record n Times instead of the n Distinct Records

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, one-to-many

We're trying to create JPA mappings atop some read only tables we imported from somebody else's application. These are multiple 10-billion row tables, so changing their schemas is not an option. We've got one table, the Message table, which has an OBJECT_ID value and another table, the DistributionGroup table, which will have many rows of ENTITY_IDs associated with any given OBJECT_ID. The relevant table definitions are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Message (
OBJ_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FileName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
KEY FileName (FileName)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE DistributionGroup (
OBJ_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
ENTITY_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
KEY OBJ_ID (OBJ_ID)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And the JPA mapping to link these two:

```
public class MessageRecord {
    private String obj_id;
    private String file;
    private List<DGRecord> list = new ArrayList<DGRecord>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OBJ_ID", nullable = false)
    public String getObjID () { return obj_id; }
    public void setObjID (String obj_id) { this.obj_id = obj_id; }
    //... (Similar for FileName)

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="OBJ_ID", referencedColumnName="OBJ_ID")
    public List<DGRecord> getDGRecordList() { return list; }
    public void setDGRecordList(List<DGRecord> list) { this.list = list; }
}

public class DGRecord {
    private String obj_id;
    private String entity_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OBJ_ID", nullable = false)
    public String getObjID () { return obj_id; }
    public void setObjID (String obj_id) { this.obj_id = obj_id; }

    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    public String getEntityId () { return entity_id; }
    public void setEntityId (String entity_id) { this.entity_id = entity_id; }
}
```

Now, the strange bit happens when we're running some code to iterate over all of the DGRecords for a given MessageRecord:

```
MessageRecord record = [obtained earlier];
for (DGRecord dg : record.getDGRecordList()) {
    System.out.println(dg.getEntityId());
    //Do some work with the ENTITY_ID
}
```

When I run this operation manually against the database, I get what I'm expecting to see:

```
SELECT * FROM DistributionGroup WHERE OBJ_ID = 'ArbitraryObjID';
OBJ_ID, ENTITY_ID
ArbitraryObjID, EntityID1
ArbitraryObjID, EntityID2
ArbitraryObjID, EntityID3
```

But the output from the actual code, when `record` has the same `ArbitraryObjID`, is:

```
EntityID1
EntityID1
EntityID1
```

For any given combination, it's not returning n different DGRecords, but the same DGRecord values n times, where n is the number of distinct rows returned by manually running the query. I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but it's actually looping over the same object n times (evidenced by System.out.println(dg) returning the same package.DistributionGroup@MemoryAddress n times).

What are we doing wrong, and how can we fix it? Keep in mind that table schema changes, or adding a join table, are so costly as to be effectively impossible. But it seems like this should still be able to work given the current setup, since it works well enough as a human.

Comment: `[obtained earlier]`, is that using some query?

Comment: Yeah. There's a lot of logic built into it, but ideally we query the Message table on FileName and get one result. Or do a bunch of work such that we end up with a single valid MessageRecord. I verified that the MessageRecord.getObjID matched the ArbitraryObjID in the situation I'm describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mapping is wrong,

try,

```
@JoinColumn(name="OBJ_ID", referencedColumnName="ENTITY_ID")
```

Comment: No, I definitely want to do the join on the OBJ_ID of MessageRecord with the OBJ_ID of DistributionGroup. I should've made it clearer in my SELECT example, but ArbitraryObjID was some MessageRecord OBJ_ID. ENTITY_ID is the distinct but unknown value we're hoping to retrieve by doing this join.

Comment: Well your OBJ_ID doesn't seem to be unique, in your manual select you list the same ArbitraryObjID value three times, so this is the same object.  If it is not unique then also mark the getEntityId as @Id.

Comment: Ah-ha! OBJ_ID is not unique, and ENTITY_ID isn't even indexed. I think what was throwing me off was that there wasn't any primary key defined for the table, nor any guarantees of uniqueness. I wasn't even previously aware that tables could be defined without requiring some column(s) to be unique, but that's neither here nor there. What is here is that that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add @Id Annotation to ENTITY_ID column

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
  public String getEntityId () { return entity_id; }
  public void setEntityId (String entity_id) { this.entity_id = entity_id; }
```